# Word for a small background program launched by a larger main application

Tags: single-word-requests

In our software project, we are quickly gaining a number of small, external programs which are not part of the main program. Each of them has a specific, but limited functionality. We're having trouble coming up with a descriptive, evocative name for them.

What all of these "things" have in common:

- They have a strictly delineated functionality.
- They are completely decoupled from the main program, but are rather useless without it.
- They usually run in their own process, or as a thread in a larger "container" program.
- They run in the background, typically listening for specific kinds of events and notifying the main program.
- The main program can start/stop these at will. The main program will typically start one of these, have them run for a while, and then shut them down again once it's no longer needed.
- The main program communicates with and controls them through some form of RPC or socket-based communication.
- They do not necessarily need to run on the same host as the main program.

We're looking for a word that denotes a small thing spawned by a larger thing, for the benefit and use of that larger thing. The obvious words with which I can come up (e.g., *component*, *module*, *service*, *task*, *agent*, *stub*, ...) already have defined meanings within the context of our project. Additionally, generic terms such as *process*, *child*, or *daemon* may cause confusion when used to refer to things which are not part of our application.

**Example sentence:**

*Any component (e.g., a service or task module), may require an ________ to be spawned. This can be done either directly by the agent, if on the same host, or by a stub on a remote host.*

Comment: Applet? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet This question is better asked on a related tech SE instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on a technical site.

Comment: Perhaps *helper application*. (Or something involving *helper*.)

Comment: Trigger?   Because they watch for events to trigger a notification to the main program.  I have seen APIs that allow you to register triggers.

Answer (score 4):

"Daemon" is sometimes used to indicate a small program that is launched and then left running in the background to provide a service.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) or [TechTarget](https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/daemon).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but one of the features of our application involves managing system daemons, which is why I'm looking for a word which clearly marks the difference between (system) daemons and "daemons" which are really just a part of our overall application/solution.